# AspectJ Pointcut on Methods with Multiple Annotations

Tags: java, annotations, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Use load-time weaving, pure AspectJ.

We have 2 annotations `@Time` and `@Count`, and a few annotated methods.

```
@Time (name="myMethod1Time")
@Count (name="myMethod1Count")
public void myMethod1(){..};

@Time (name="myMethod2Time")
public void myMethod2(){..};

@Count (name="myMethod3Count")
public void myMethod3(){..};
```

Now I am defining my own around aspect for `myMethod1` which has multiple annotations:

```
// multiple annotations, not working
@Around("@annotation(time) && @annotation(count))
public Object myAspect(Time time, Count count) {..}
```

This doesn't work. However, capture method `myMethod2` works fine with a single annotation:

```
// single annotation, is working
@Around("@annotation(time))
public Object myAnotherAspect(Time time) {..}
```

I want to capture only methods with both `Time` and `Count` annotations present in their signature, and I want to use the annotation value. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: I'll just comment that it works for pure AspectJ - just tried it - so perhaps using it in spring-aop is the problem. (However, in pure AspectJ you'd also want to use an `execution(* *(..))` otherwise it will match the call of the annotated method and the execution of the annotated method - the advise will run twice per method)

Comment: I am using pure AspectJ with load-time weaving, it doesn't work for me, sounds strange.

Comment: Maybe raise an AspectJ bug, or post a more complete failing program and I can dig into it. All I've tried so far is stitching together what you posted above.

Comment: how to change call sequence of multiple APOs ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe combine 2 pointcuts like:

```
@Around("call(@Time * *(..)) && call(@Count * *(..))");
```