# Spring AOP with custom annotation on @Bean method

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I'm trying to use AOP with annotation triggering as you can see in this pointcut

```
package mypackage.aop;

// ...

@Aspect
@Component
public class ErrorHandlerAspect {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorHandlerAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("within(mypackage.config.steps..*) && @annotation(mypackage.aop.SaveAndErrors)")
    private void pointcut(){ }

    @Around("pointcut()")
    private Object errorHandler(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
        try{
            return pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e){
            LOGGER.error("Handling error");
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are declaration of annotation :

```
package mypackage.aop;

// ...

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SaveAndErrors { }
```

... and usage in @Configuration class (for spring batch step configuration) :

```
package mypackage.config.steps;

// ...

@Configuration
public class StepConfiguration {

    public final static String STEP_NAME = "xStep";

    // ...

    @SaveAndErrors
    @Bean(name="xFileReader")
    @StepScope
    public ItemStreamReader<Object> xFileReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String resourceName // Inside a partitionner) throws xException {
        try {
            // ...
            // return ...
        } catch (yException e) {
            throw new xException("new Exception :", e);
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

And my Application class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application { //...
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working.
Removing  && @annotation(mypackage.aop.SaveAndErrors) from pointcut, my aop proxy is working.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: I am not a Spring user, I use pure AspectJ. But from what little I know I thought that Spring AOP only applies to `@Component`s. If it also works for `@Configuration` entities I cannot say, but that might be the problem. When you say that the aspect works when removing the second condition, have you really verified (e.g. with a log statement) that it is also triggered for method `xFileReader`?

Comment: Hi. When I remove the statement, the debugger is stopping on my stoppoint : return pjp.proceed();

I also tried an other way, using only `@annotation` with a method (with only my SaveAndErrors annotation) of a bean (outside `@configuration` classe). The aspect is called too.

Comment: I do not understand your last comment. I have no idea what you tried to tell me, sorry. What is "the statement", where is "your stoppoint", what is "a method"? Maybe you should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), possibly on GitHub.

Comment: Hi. I configure this pointcut :  `@Pointcut("@annotation(mypackage.aop.SaveAndErrors)")` and I set `@SaveAndErrors` on `@Component
public class A{

    @SaveAndErrors
    public void operation() throws xException {
        try {
            // return ...
        } catch (yException e) {
            throw new xException("new Exception :", e);
        }
    }

}`
In this case, my aspect is called.

Comment: As I said, class `StepConfiguration` is not a `@Component`.

Comment: Yes. But AOP works with `@Configuration` too. If the pointcut only contains `@Pointcut("within(mypackage.config.steps..*))`, then my aspect will catch any call to `xFileReader`

Comment: Then I see no obvious reason why it should not work, other than typos. Please extract a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share it on GitHub so as to make the problem reproduceable.

Comment: Here is [Issue demo](https://github.com/flynet01/sof-springbatch-aop-issue)

Comment: Unfortunately, my github account has been flagged for now. I will tell you when the link will be enable again

Comment: That's good. My account is enabled again : [Github issue demo](https://github.com/flynet01/sof-springbatch-aop-issue)

Comment: I made some updates. 3 Jobs : 
sampleJob : use tasklet with annotation aspect (working),
sampleJobBis : use a factory for create reader. create method of the factory is annoted (working),
sampleJobTer : no factory but same concept : all in reader bean declaration (not working),

WorkingAnnotedAspect : an aspect that's working on a bean declaration

Comment: And now what is your issue? I see in the log output that all 3 aspects in the repository are being triggered.

Comment: `IssueAspect` should be executed when `sampleStepReader` (`SampleIssueStepConfiguration`) is called. And this could be done without using a factory (`sampleWorkingStepReader` in `SampleWorkingStepConfiguration`)

Comment: I see, and I have no idea. Maybe aspects really are not meant to be applied to configurations and it is just by accident that the pointcut in `WorkingAspect` works. To me at least configuration comes before application or aspect logic. You do not want to have interceptable logic there. You should ask in a Spring forum, I am not a Spring user. BTW, why do you manually instantiate your aspects as beans? Get rid of the config class and just annotate the aspects by `@Component`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems that some other thread relate the same issue : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995233/aspectj-pointcut-on-methods-with-multiple-annotations), (http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/68778-using-multiple-annotations-aspects-on-the-same-method). But there is no answer.

Comment: Think about it for a moment: While you are still wiring beans and aspects, you already want to apply them. This ius a classical bootstrapping problem. You could get unpredictable results, and obviously you do. P.S.: I do not think the two issues you linked to are the same as this one. IMO they are unrelated.